# Creating disk image with msdos partition table and fat32

Tags: disk-image, partition-table

I want to create a disk image file to include into my unittests. This disk file should contain a few files afterwards I want to read. When I create a copy of a SD card or a USB stick with `dd` the disk image is quite large, even when I compress it, the size is too large.

So I want to create a new disk image and mount it afterwards. Then adding new data and compressing the disk image for version control

My current steps:

1. Create disk image: `dd if=/dev/zero of=DISK1.img bs=1M count=1200`
2. Open parted: `sudo parted DISK1.img`
3. Create partition table (with parted): `mklabel msdos`
4. Create partition (with parted): `mkpart primary fat32 1MB 100%`
5. Print:

   ```
   (parted) print                                                            
   Modell:  (file)
   Festplatte  <path>/DISK1.img:  1258MB
   Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
   Partitionstabelle: msdos
   Disk-Flags: 

   Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Typ      Dateisystem  Flags
    1      1049kB  1258MB  1257MB  primary  fat32        lba
   ```

Now when I quit and reopen parted the filesystem is not recognized anymore:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Modell:  (file)
Festplatte  <path>/DISK1.img:  1258MB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: msdos
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Typ      Dateisystem  Flags
 1      1049kB  1258MB  1257MB  primary               lba
```

How do I create an image from scratch?

#### EDIT 2024-03-02

Using the comment from @Stephen Kitt it worked:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=DISK1.img bs=1M count=1200`
2. `parted DISK1.img`
3. Create partition table (with parted): `mklabel msdos`
4. Create partition (with parted): `mkpart primary fat32 1MB 100%`
5. Quit parted
6. `mkfs.vfat -v --offset 2048 DISK1.img`

To mount the partition:

1. Find startsector: `fdisk -lu DISK1.img` (same as above)
2. Get offset in bytes: 512bytes * 2048sectors = 1048576
3. lopsetup partition: `sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 DISK1.img`
4. Mount: `sudo mount /dev/loop0 DISK_MOUNT`
5. Copy data to mounted partition (Root required)
6. unmount `sudo umount /dev/loop0`
7. Detach losetup: `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`

Now the new data is in the disk image

Comment: Good use cases of `dd` are rare these days. You'd be better to allocate with `fallocate` or `truncate` instead as these will be quicker and not waste time writing to disk needlessly.

Comment: On modern systems, `sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 DISK1.img` will give you `/dev/loop0p1` which you can mount directly, without a need to calculate offsets manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parted` creates the partition table and the partition entry, but you also need to create the file system: exit `parted` after step 5, then create the file system with the appropriate offset (I’m using `-v` so that `mkfs.vfat` shows what it’s doing):

```
$ /sbin/mkfs.vfat -v --offset 2048 DISK1.img
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Auto-selecting FAT32 for large filesystem
DISK1.img has 64 heads and 63 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 2455551 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 8 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 2400 sectors, and provides 306339 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 97413b09, no volume label.
```

This will format the first partition (starting at sector 2048) as a FAT32 volume. When you reload the image in `parted`, it will show this:

```
$ /sbin/parted DISK1.img
…
(parted) print
Disk …/DISK1.img: 1258MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1258MB  1257MB  primary  fat32        lba
```

In general, to determine the appropriate offset when working with images, you can change the units in `parted` to sectors:

```
(parted) unit s                                                           
(parted) print                                                            
Model:  (file)
Disk …/DISK1.img: 2457600s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s  2457599s  2455552s  primary  fat32        lba
```

(Note that since you’re working on your own disk image, you don’t need `sudo`, you only need to specify the full path to `parted` and `mkfs.vfat` since they are in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` and therefore not on your `PATH`.)

If you don’t *need* a partition table in your image, you might find it easier to work with a file system image rather than a full disk image; you can do everything in one command with `mkfs.vfat`:

```
$ /sbin/mkfs.vfat -v -C DISK2.img $((1200*1024))
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Auto-selecting FAT32 for large filesystem
DISK2.img has 64 heads and 63 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 2457567 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 8 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 2400 sectors, and provides 306591 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is a452a0bf, no volume label.
```

Comment: So I had the right step, just in the wrong place.... Darn I was close....

Comment: And missing the offset, which is the key ingredient here.

Comment: @StephenKitt :  There is so much conflicting info about this, can you recommend a good tutorial? Tnx and understand if you honor "requests for tutorials are off-topic".

Comment: @shellter it’s been a very long time since I looked at tutorials on this kind of thing, I’m afraid I don’t have one to recommend.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This worked fine :). I tried to mount the image to push some data in, but then I get an error message that loop0 is broken

Answer (score 1):

Your Steps are correct, just add:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 DISK1.img` after Step 1 in, and before step 2 in your procedure.

See the [mkfs.vfat manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.html)

Comment: That will create a file system, just for it to be rendered unusable by the partition table written on top of it...

Comment: @StephenKitt The `parted` step isn't saving the filesystem anyway.  This ensures that the filesystem is at least written and synced to the disk.  If the OP doesn't want to overwrite what's created he can just remove parted from his workflow

Comment: The partition table is shown after quitting and restarting `parted`, which indicates that the changes made in `parted` *are* written to the image. Note the title of the question: the stated goal is to create an image with a partition table, not just a file system.

Comment: @StephenKitt Seeing as the `parted` option isn't working, this might be a viable replacement for Step 4 altogether.  Could [See Parted Footnote](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mkpart.html) be part of the problem?  I didn't think so, as this is a file and not an actual device.  I'm going to repeat the steps on my Gentoo Box later today and see if I get the same result as the OP

Comment: No, you still need step 4 to create the partition. See my answer.

Comment: Yes this step did not help